# Price moving patterns change over time?

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

As I do technical analysis on stocks, forex pairs, cryptos, see its chart and price data, I came to think of that if some major technical analysis indicators such as RSI were once effective in the past, like 1940's or 1960's, or even in the further past.

I mean in the current financial market, trading only seeing RSI for example, is nearly unreal in my opinion. You cannot simply win the market just buy or sell when its RSI is under 20 (over sold) or over 80 (over bought). Same to the MACD, MAs etc.

So my curiosity is that in the past one or some of these indicators were effective compared to the current market? In other words, the price moving patterns were different to now's or it has been the same? If the price moving patterns change over time in the history, from around when, how significantly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such indicators are any more or any less effective today than years ago.

The periodicity of the market varies.  At times it will oscillate. At times it will trend.  Trend following indicators will do well in trending periods.  Non trend following indicators do well in non trending periods. Use the wrong on and the results are kaka.

If you have a large block of historical data and you optimize an indicator over the first half of it (curve fitting), you'll determine the optimal periodicity for that indicator.  If you then use that optimized indicator on the second half of the data, many times it will lose dramatically.  It won't matter if the data period is from the 1960s or the 2000s.

Another problem (at all times) with these indicators is that they are derivatives of price and can lose their connection with price.  As a quick example, many believe that if the MACD turns up it's a buy signal and if it turns down, it's a sell signal and that's not always true.  An indicator reversal when below zero can be false as is a reversal above zero (a reversal to the upside when above zero can only be valid and vice versa on the downside).  You'd have to understand the mathematics of the MACD's formula to recognize this.

My two cents is that technical analysis indicators are like looking in a rearview mirror, telling you where you have been.  At best, they can identify a trend but any position taken is based on the hope that the trend continues.  They predict nothing going forward.